# SSH using Agent Forwarding with Windows Host OS, Vagrant Ubuntu Guest OS, and Keepass/Keeagent

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, vagrant

**Intent**: To be able to deploy to `lan-example.com` from any dev environment; whether it be directly from the virtual OS, or any single-OS system, or even over the internet using ONE SSH key stored in Keepass. I'm currently unable to do so from within Vagrant's OS unless I explicitly generate its own key and authorize it in each of my deployment servers. I believe the way to do what I want is through User Agent Forwarding, yes?

---

**Host OS**

- Windows 7 x64
- SSH key generated by puttygen: `C:\Users\Administrator\.ssh\id_rsa.ppk`
- Keepass with Keeagent storing my SSH key. Keeagent is set to "Agent" mode
- pageant.exe is installed but is not running
- If I wish to connect to outside/internal LAN servers using my key, Putty defers to Keeagent - Putty does not store the private key locations in its configuration.

C:\Users\Administrator.ssh\config

```
Host 192.168.55.2
  ForwardAgent yes
```

Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: '192.168.55.2'
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  # Why would I need to set this if Keeagent is handling things?
  config.ssh.private_key_path = '~/.ssh/id_rsa_jake_mitchell.ppk'
end
```

---

**Guest OS (Vagrant)**

- Ubuntu x64
- 192.168.55.2, accessible through host only
- No SSH keys exist in `/home/vagrant/.ssh` (I removed them). The intent is to let User Agent Forwarding through the host OS (Keeagent) take care of using the key

---

**LAN Web Host (intranet websites)**

- Let's say its domain is `lan-example.com`
- It allows SSH passwordless login only using id_rsa.ppk public key
- 192.168.0.2
- User Agent Forwarding is enabled in sshd

---

**Problem:**

What works (using Host OS): Putty, connecting to `lan-example.com` without the need to explicitly reference the SSH key.

What doesn't work (using Guest OS): `ssh -v web-server@lan-example.com` as it shows that there aren't any keys to use.

I've noticed something about the [beta version of Keeagent](http://lechnology.com/software/keeagent/usage/options-and-settings/) that allows me to set the SSH_AUTH_SOCK. I've done so, and set up an NFS share that allows the guest OS to read the file; however this doesn't change anything. How does agent forwarding even work in this type of environment? What's different about Windows that causes this to fail?

Comment: A duplicate of this was posted and answered on https://serverfault.com/questions/662865/ssh-using-agent-forwarding-with-windows-host-os-vagrant-ubuntu-guest-os-and-ke

Answer (score 1):

You need to ssh from the host OS (using PuTTY on Windows) with agent forwarding enabled. Then from that session, ssh from the guest OS to the server.

[image: PuTTY Agent Forwarding Settings]